# Why a meta ensemble of ensemble models works well?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, ensemble-learning

Why is ensembling the predictions of an ensemble model effective in improving test error? Is there any literature that discusses the theory behind this?

In fact, ensembling GBMs or LGBMs is widely used in competitions such as Kaggle. As I understand it, GBMs and LGBMs are ensemble models of decision trees. For many types of datasets, ensembles of decision tree ensembles seem to perform better than just ensembles of decision trees. Why?